# coding style while accessing property for the first time and backing field member is null

Tags: c#, coding-style, readability

I am looking if there is elegant way to make sure when property is accessed first time, associated backing field is set. For example, I end up lot with below code paradigm to address this :

```
private Address _address;
        public Address Address
        {
            get
            {
                if (_address == null)
                {
                    _address = GetAddress();
                }return _address;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please specify language in tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless error prone or time consuming, I would suggest populating the property in the constructor. Otherwise, I suggest using [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) to do it, for thread safety:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Address _address;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _address = GetAddress();
    }

    public Address Address {get {return _address;}}
}
```

Using `Lazy<T>`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Lazy<Address> _address;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _address = new Lazy<Address>(() => GetAddress());
    }

    public Address Address {get {return _address.Value;}}
}
```

Starting with c#6, you can have an auto-implemented property like this, but then you have to make the `GetAddress()` method `static`:

```
public Address Addgress {get;} = GetAddress();
```

That will translate to something like the first option I've shown - [See SharpLab demo.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4CyAngMIA2AhgM5UYDeGcTCOx51VAFAJSPMPpmcPkwC+GESzgBBYMABOAUxoy5SlXQDmigC7JRcALxwA4rtkLlXbmkHNJAB3kBLAG4UdihIgBsqyypmOhbq1nB0cDoAFvIA9gDucAB2iokAcrE6AJIAtg5kijmKSZ7AAKIAHgDGig46zrFJPPoY4ugY2Hj+oeGiQA==)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple method to DRY up the property code a bit:

```
private T GetInstance<T>(ref T instance, Func<T> getInstance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = getInstance();
    return instance;
}

private Address _address;
public Address Address => GetInstance<Address>(ref _address, () => GetAddress());

private string _name;
public string Name => GetInstance<string>(ref _name, () => GetName());
```

EDIT: After looking into the article @Zohar kindly pointed out in the comments, I expect using `Lazy` is a better way to go as you get thread safety with good performance. So to make it look as neat as possible (IMO) this would be done as:

```
private readonly Lazy<Address> _address = new Lazy<Address>(() => GetAddress());
public Address Address => _address.Value;
```

Comment: This is not thread safe, and also far less readable then using `Lazy` or the auto implemented property `public Address Addgress {get;} = GetAddress();` you get out of the box in c#6.

Comment: That initialises the property instantly. Whereas this answer initialises on demand, which is the point of having the private and public. Why is this not thread safe?

Comment: using `Lazy` also initialize on demand. This is not thread save because two different threads could both have evaluated the test `if (instance==null)` and found it to be `true`, then both create instances. Further reading - Jon Skeet's [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: Yes `Lazy` does init on demand, but `{ get; } = GetAddress();` does not. It's unlikely that this will be an issue with thread safety as it is within an instance of the contained class. But it could easily be made into a thread safe static method.

Comment: You've changed my mind @Zohar. Lazy is the way to go and I will probably start using it myself.

Comment: Lazy does have it's benefits :-).

Answer (score 0):

Assign the property value in the constructor itself, like this

```
private Address _address;
public Address Address
{
  get { return _address; }
}

public ABC() //Constructor 
{
  _address = GetAddress();
}
```

Comment: If `GetAddress()` is an expensive method, and the ´Address` might not be used then I prefer the OP's solution.

Comment: but this is like i am instantiating an object and might not access that property at all. Doing that while accessing property looks kind of lazy initialization, isn't it ? not sure if this all boils down to some code smell..